# Appropriate copper pipe length for shutoff valves

Tags: copper, shutoff

We recently renovated our home and paid to have the plumbing roughed in.  I am planning to try and tackle the kitchen sink installation.  I have 1/4 turn angle stops for the hot/cold water for the kitchen sink.  Is there a recommended amount of length to leave on the copper pipes coming from the wall that I will install the angle stop on?  The stub outs are about 3 inches right now.

Comment: Are you sweating them or are they screw in?

Comment: I was going to use the compression ones (is that screw in?).  Here is a link:  https://www.homedepot.com/p/BrassCraft-1-2-in-Nominal-Compression-Inlet-x-3-8-in-O-D-Compression-Outlet-1-4-Turn-Angle-Valve-G2CR19X-C1/202047059

Comment: Personally I would not cut off 3" long stub outs. If the cuts are rough, you should deburr both the insides and outsides of the cuts. Don't overtighten the compression nut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would leave the pipes at there current length. The reason I would leave the extra length is if you have problems with the compression fitting leaking now or in the future you will have enough space to cut it off and put a new fitting on.